# Attr object indexing issue inside NamedNodeMap object

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, google-chrome

What does standard specify about indexing sequence with Attr objects inside NamedNodeMap object?

I am getting reverse sequence in firefox and chrome.

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" name="test_form" id="test_form">

element = document.getElementById("test_form");
element.attributes.item(0);
element.attributes.item(1);
element.attributes.item(2);
element.attributes.item(3);
```

Firefox:

```
id="test_form"
name="test_form"
method="post"
action="test.php"
```

Chrome:

```
action="test.php"
method="post"
name="test_form"
id="test_form"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1780488922) says:

> NamedNodeMaps are not maintained in any particular order. Objects
>   contained in an object implementing NamedNodeMap may also be accessed
>   by an ordinal index, but this is simply to allow convenient
>   enumeration of the contents of a NamedNodeMap, and does not imply that
>   the DOM specifies an order to these Nodes.

So, not sorted.